# How to write header only once in the CSV file per execution in jmeter

Tags: java, csv, jmeter

I am preparing one BeanShell PostProcessor script to write data into CSV file in Jmeter.

Here is my Code

```
try {
    File file = new File("samplefile.csv");
    FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file, true);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);
    BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

     List list = new ArrayList();
     String[] header={"no"};
     String[] id = {"${myNo}"};
     list.add(header);
     list.add(id);
     writer.writeAll(list);                             
     writer.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Here, I want to write header into the file only once in the top row of my csv file. But every time, I execute the script, header gets entered per sample user. here, I am using openCSV jars to read/write data

I also tried with apache commons csv jars, but I was not able to execute the code, I got an error
here is the code of appache common csv

```
 try (
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("sample.csv"));

        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withHeader("NO");
    ) {
        csvPrinter.printRecord("${myNo}");
        csvPrinter.flush();            
    }
```

> ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import java.nio.file.Files; import java.ni . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 8, column 10.

> WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import java.nio.file.Files; import java.ni . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 8, column 10.

> ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import java.nio.file.Files; import java.ni . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 8, column 10.

> WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import java.nio.file.Files; import java.ni . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 8, column 10.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the whole scipt including all the import .... statement? 
I assume that you didn't add the CSV related classes properly.

Comment: hey Sean, thanks for your response, here are the imports of Apache Commons CSV
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

My OpenCSV code is working fine but the issue is it adds title after the execution of every sample, & with apache common csv, the script is throwing an error I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

1. "Your" code won't work because it doesn't have proper syntax for the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html), correct one would be something like:

   ```
   try {
       BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("sample.csv"));

       CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
               .withHeader("NO"));
       csvPrinter.printRecord("${myNo}");
       csvPrinter.flush();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       log.error("Failure in script: ", ex)
   }
   ```
2. If you want the header to be written only once - either do something like:

   ```
   if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 0) {
       list.add(header);
   }
   ```

   or even better write the header somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) as I don't know how many users you have and what are the ramp-up settings
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it's a good idea to consider migrating.
4. In case of concurrent users your approach will stop working, due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) multiple users will be writing into the same file at the same time resulting in data corruption or loss, it's better to use [Flexbile File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

Comment: The FileWriter part,  need consider the concurrent accessing indeed.